# how to execute style code in a php variable to html textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have a php variable:

```
$correction = <span style="background:yellow">iiii</span> am a good person.
```

This variable is sent to ajax from php under the

```
success: function(msg)
{       
    $("#target").val(msg); // msg is the $correction string
}
```

then it gets displayed into a textarea. However, i want the style to execute instead of displaying the html code in the $correction.

It detects misspelling and highlights it in yellow but i have no ideas how to make it display the string.

I have tried creating a function in the ajax success function and send the msg variable to a Javascript function but it did not work.

I have tried adding `<body></body>` tag on it and even replaced the

`<span> to <div id="display" style="background:yellow">iiii</div> am a good person.`

and it still did not work.

expected result: `<mark>iiii</mark> am a good person.`

actual result:  `<span style="background:yellow">iiii</span> am a good person.`

Thanks for helping.

Comment: How do you pass your variable to ajax? ps. Change into this your variable php declaration $correction = "<span style=\"background:yellow\">iiii</span> am a good person.";

Comment: Thank you. I used the str_ireplace function from php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set an HTML - Code inside an `<textarea/>` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp because it is an "multi-line text input" object.

If you want it inside an textarea, you can do it with an `<div contenteditable="true">your editable content</div>` workaround on an DIV-tag.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp

Comment: I managed to workaround with contenteditable as you suggested. it is working fine but a bug is messing with me. it highlights all wrongly written words if and only if the first word of the sentence is also wrongly written.